# Value doesn't appear on next line

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to achieve an output with some contents in the table. All looks good to me, but the only issue I am facing is that the value under H1 column appears in same line.

Is there a way, I could make this appear in next line? Of course, removing commas and braces.

Here is the code:

```
$Csv = Import-Csv -Path $file

$Csv | Group-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object -Process {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      N1 = $_.Name
      T1 = ($_.Group.TOtal |Measure -sum).Sum
      H1 = $_.Group.Hired
      C1 = $_.Group.Count
      
    }
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
N1     T1 H1                 C1
--     -- --                 --
John    3 2002                1
David 150 {2011, 2003, 2011}  3
Steve  55 {2012, 2003}        2
Jason 550 {2001, 2002}        2
```

**Desired Output:**

```
N1     T1 H1                 C1
--     -- --                 --
John    3 2002                1
David 150 2011                3
          2003
          2011
...
```

Comment: Can you please provide an inpout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired output by explicitly calling `Format-Table` like this:

```
$CSV |Format-Table N1,T1,@{Name='H1';Expression={$_.H1 -join "`n"}},C1 -Wrap
```

The calculated property expression:

```
{$_.H1 -join "`n"}
```

makes `Format-Table` display `H1` as a multi-line string. `-Wrap` prevents `Format-Table` from truncating multi-line strings - giving us something like:

```
N1     T1 H1             C1
--     -- --             --
John    3 2002            1
David 150 2011            3
          2003
          2011
Steve  55 2012            2
          2003
Jason 550 2001            2
          2002
```

If you want to preserve the newlines when *exporting* to a CSV file, use `Select-Object` instead:

```
$CSV |Select-Object N1,T1,@{Name='H1';Expression={$_.H1 -join "`n"}},C1 |Export-Csv .\output_with_newlines.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Converting to HTML is as easy as piping the resulting objects to `ConvertTo-Html -As Table`:

```
$CSV |Select N1,T1,@{Name='H1';Expression={$_.H1 -join "`n"}},C1 |ConvertTo-Html -As Table |Set-Content .\path\to\report.html
```

By default, your browser will render the newlines as regular spaces, but this can be solved by injecting a bit of CSS:

```
$style = @'
<style>
  table {
    white-space: pre;
    vertical-align:top;
  }
</style>
'@

$CSVMultiLine = $CSV |Select N1,T1,@{Name='H1';Expression={$_.H1 -join "`n"}},C1 
$CSVMultiLine |ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Head $style |Set-Content .\path\to\report.html
```

`white-space: pre` will render newlines as-is, and `vertical-align: top` ensures the first line of each column is always aligned. Add your own styling as required.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mathias.

Comment: I realize, after exporting it to csv it combine the data into System Object also, I am looking how to convert this data to HTML as well.

Comment: @Sarah You're welcome! :) When exporting to CSV you definitely don't want the output from `Format-*`, use `Select-Object` instead. Updated the answer with an example of how to format/style it as an HTML table as well

Comment: I processed the script with HTML Report send to the email. However, always the first column header displays as Bottom Align. if I remove white-space: pre, it resolved the issue but the Wrap gets destroyed. Wonder, what I am missing. Thank you.